# TortoiseGit remote settings don't adhere to config scope

Tags: config, tortoisegit

In the TortosieGit settings dialog Remote is a sub menu item to Git (the menu item Git, not the program itself).

[image: Settings Menu]

If I select Global for the config scope and enter a remote it does not get entered in the global config but instead gets added to the local config. If I manually enter a remote into the global config file Tortoise reports it correctly under the global setting. Am I missing something? I want to have a single global config file with all my remotes listed.

TortoiseGit 2.15.0.0 / Windows 10 Pro 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no config scope selection for the remotes tab. The config source selection onyl affects the currently selected tab.

Comment: I guess I need to mention it to the TortoiseGit folks. Seems a bit misleading to have Remote be a sub entry under where the config scope is set.